# Positionned absolute, but still contained in screen

Tags: css, window, position, absolute

I have an html table. When I click on a row, i pop a helper block at the left of the row. This helper block has the following CSS :

```
.row-helper-tooltip {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #ec101f;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    float: right;
    left: -149px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: -3px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 145px;
}
```

My table is contained in a 1000px container. So on a large screen, everything works fine. But on a 1024px wide screen, the helper-block is poped out of the screen. How can I make it be contained in window and still be positonned absolute ?

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: need more of your html and css to find whats going on your tooltip. A fiddle may be helpful.